# Angular code not connecting to my spring backend properly

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I was trying to update my Jhipster 4.0 project (which used Angular 4) to Jhipster 6.0 (which used Angular 9). There was such a difference in the angular version and typescript version, that I instead did just created a Jhipster 6.0 project, and then I replaced all of the following files in this Jhipster 6.0 project. These files were replaced with the files from the Jhipster 4.0 project, so I could get the front-end working again
  - src/main/webapp
  - src/test
  - package.json
  - webpack
  - tsconfig.json

In essence this makes it use angular 4 again ... makes it use the old typescript ... and lets it have all of the old front-end code. I can bring the application app just fine (using ./mvnvw and npm start) ... but then I notice that when I go to my frontend (http://localhost:9001/#/dash) , it tries to connect to the java backend at localhost:9001/api/apps, which gives an error of -> `Error occurred while trying to proxy to: localhost:9061/api/apps`

However when I started the app with mvnw... it starts up the backend on `http://localhost:8080/api/apps`. So how can I get this to stop talking to `localhost:9001/api/apps` and instead talk to `http://localhost:8080/api/apps`.

I'm running my backend with ./mvnw ... and then I start up the front-end with npm start

And here is my webpack.dev.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'development';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './target/www',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console',
                '/auth'
            ],
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081',
            secure: false
        }],
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        }
    },
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('target/www'),
        filename: 'app/[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loaders: 'tslint-loader',
            exclude: ['node_modules', new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
        },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'awesome-typescript-loader'
                ],
                exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9001,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:9061' // TODO - original
                // target: 'http://localhost:8080' // TODO - original
            }
        }, {
            reload: false
        }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new writeFilePlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
            utils.root('src/test'),
        ]),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            title: 'JHipster',
            contentImage: path.join(__dirname, 'logo-jhipster.png')
        })
    ]
});
```

Comment: do u have proxy configuration file in angular project? what is the command you are using to start angular development server?

Comment: @Plochie I'm running my backend with ./mvnw ... and then I start up the front-end with npm start

Answer (score 2):

By default if you made any `http` request from angular dev server with just URL (e.g. `/api/someapi`) then it will get routed to angular dev server only.

You can use proxy configuration while running the angular dev server to route the data to desired target.

Create `proxy.conf.json` in your project root directory.

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Then start the angular dev server by running `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Comment: So I'm running my backend with ./mvnw ... and then I start up the front-end with `npm start`, which maps to `yarn run webpack:dev`. When I do your command instead of the `npm start`, it complained about my typescript version, so I did `npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'`, and now it says `Cannot read property 'config' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null at Class.run (/Users/mike.knoth/IdeaProjects/up/portal-new-keycloak/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:51:63)`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Plochie, would adding this proxy and adding "ng serve" help only for developer scenarios? Is it basically creating a proxy so that angular requests to "/api" get routed to the appropriate backend?

Comment: @AdamWise You are correct, this is only while developing application. While deploying this in production, you ll need to configure the hosting server accordingly. At the end Angular will just generate static files which you ll need to serve from some server.

Comment: @MikeK. So your errors are not very informative. What I have done is to delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` then to check the version compatibility of installed dependancies and finally install the dependencies again.

Comment: For me JHipster 7.0 worked out of the box with mvn and ng serve in parrallel. When I created my own backend service, I only needed to follow the scheme "/api/<entity>/". Somewhere in the magic of JHipster it is redirected correctly.